# Как сменить порт подкключения к vmware esxi 5.5 c 443 на другой?

Tags: vmware

Как сменить порт подключения к `VMware Esxi 5.5` c `443` на другой из `Vsphere Client`?

Comment: [официальная документция](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021199). в чем ваша проблема?

Answer (score 1):

1. подключаемся к хосту.
2. редактируем /host/proxy.xml
3. находим тэг `<ConfigRoot>` и внутри заменяем значение поля 
   `<httpsPort>443</httpsPort>` на другой. например 
   `<httpsPort>8081</httpsPort>`.
4. перезагружаем сервер

Весь трафик по https будет перенаправлен по другому порту.

Вот [официальная документация](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021199)

Comment: Если бы я знал как подключиться к хосту еще, было бы здорово...

Comment: 22 порт у меня проброшен на сервер виртуальный.

Comment: по ssh вообще нет доступа к серверу ?  Тогда можно с помощью vifs скачать к себе. изменть и отправить на сервер

Comment: Сервер стоит рядом со мной, в одной сети. Просто за 3 года я ни разу не пытался его перенастраивать не через Vsphere Client

Comment: То есть как с ним подругому работать я не представляю. И по ssh не пытался к нему коннектиться. Клавиатура + монитор если что то надо было.

Comment: теперь настало время попробовать